# Why are member functions in C++ accessed with dot operator after object name?

Tags: c++, c++11

In Python any bound call to member funtion or method gets converted to unbound call, i.e: `obj.method()` is equivalent to `method(obj)`. That's why the first parameter of every member function is itself.

Is there a similar concept in C++ that explains why member function are accessed with dot operator?

Comment: Python is not C++.

Comment: Probably the C origins of the language where struct members were accessed with dot syntax.

Comment: That is because the proposed **uniform call syntax**  is voted to be not part of C++ (for now).

Comment: FYI: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4174.pdf

Comment: @PeteBecker I could not understand the reason too

Comment: "*Is there a similar concept in C++ that explains why member function are accessed with dot operator?*" ... as opposed to accessed with what? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your first paragraph doesn't mention *why* you can call member function using the "dot" in Python – only that it's mostly syntactic sugar – but the most likely reason is that it was well-established syntax, in C++ and dozens of other languages, at the time Guido added classes to Python (the practice is decades older than Python).

Comment: .....mm...mmm....m।।.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, the dot ('.') is an operator, which allows you to access a member given and object. There is another operator, arrow ('->') which allows you to access a member of an object given a pointer to that object. Each of these works for both member variables *and* member functions.

Inside of each (non-static) member function, the code has access to a pointer to the object ('this'), which can be used as needed. Access to members of that object are also available there.

As to *why* dots are used? It's just a design choice that Bjarne Stroustrup (PBUH) made a few decades ago.  It mimics C's access to a member of a struct.

Comment: Stroustrup did not invent `.`; it was inherited from C.

Comment: Yep. Like I said, it mimics C's access of  struct members.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such concept that makes `obj.method()` and `method(obj)` equivalent in c++. There has been a proposal for Uniform Function Call Syntax that would make them call the same code, but as far as I can tell it does not seem that it will be adopted any time soon.

Answer (score 2):

Early C++ was a superset of the C language (it was originally called ["C with Classes"](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#invention)), so the use of the `.` comes from Kernigan and Ritchie's 1973 introduction of `struct` to the C language, meaning "member of instance".

In order for the compiler to determine which function you are calling, it needs to know which object you are acting on, and so the simple decision was made to re-use the existing member-access syntax (object.member) and pass the object address as an implicit argument.

Why a pointer? Because C didn't have references.

The original C++ compiler, [CFront](http://cpp-lang.io/30-years-of-cpp-bjarne-stroustrup/), translated "C with classes" and later C++ into C code before compiling to assembly. Backwards and binary compatibility with C was critical and in order for a member function to modify the object its being invoked against, it needs to be passed by pointer or reference. Since pointers were supported by C as well as C++ they chose pointers. So `this` is a pointer, not a reference.

Roughly the same thing happens in Python, the `this` just has to be explicit by the user:

```
# Python
class MyClassNameHere(object):
    _a = -1
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 0
    def setA(self, a):
        self._a = a
    def getA(self):
        return self._a

// C++
struct MyClassNameHere {
    int a_;
    MyClassNameHere() : a_(0) {}
    void setA(int a) { a_ = a; }
    int getA() const { return a_; }
};
```

Because C++ is strongly typed, having to specify the `this` parameter would be tediously verbose, and you'd have to be mindful of your const's:

```
struct MyClassNameHere {
    int a_ = -1;
    MyClassNameHere(MyClassNameHere* this) : a_(0) {}
    void setA(MyClassNameHere* this, int a) { a_ = a; }
    int setA(const MyClassNameHere* this) const { return a_; }
    //       ^^^^^
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed as an answer. I guess I did not frame my question correctly, that's why people did not answer to the point and downvoted this question. Sadly, I could not upvote this answer though I want to as I'm a new user. Still thanks again